# How to specify bool (not tf.bool) in tf.function input_signature?

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

**Short question**

I'm creating a `tf.keras.Model` using the subclassing API. In the call method of this model, I'm calling another method. I would like to specify a `@tf.function` decorator for this method with a specific `input_signature`. But the problem is that one of my inputs is a simple `bool` (not a tensor), namely the `training` argument that is present on many keras layers such as [`tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/BatchNormalization). How can I specify a simple bool in the `input_signature` of a `@tf.function`?

Example code:

```py
class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init___(**kwargs):
        ...
        self.batch_norm = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(name="batch_norm")
        ...

    def call(self, inputs: Tuple[tf.Tensor, tf.Tensor], training: bool = False) -> tf.Tensor:
        ...
        some_result = self._my_method(inputs, training)
        ...
        return final_result

    @tf.function(
        input_signature=???  <-- What do I put here?
    )
    def _my_method(self, inputs: Tuple[tf.Tensor, tf.Tensor], training: bool = False) -> tf.Tensor:
        ...
        x_norm = self.batch_norm(x, training=training)
        ...
        return some_result
```

**Illustration of problem**

The problem is that the training argument really needs to be a python `bool`. I can specify it as a tensor of dtype `tf.bool` but this will not work. The reason is that the `fit` method on my model passes a simple `bool` not a `tf.bool` tensor to the call method, which I cannot change.

For example if I use this input signature:

```py
    ...
    @tf.function(
        input_signature=(
            (
                tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.float32, name="tensor1"),
                tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, 10), dtype=tf.float32, name="tensor2")
            ),
            tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.bool, name="training")
        )
    )
    def _my_method(self, inputs: Tuple[tf.Tensor, tf.Tensor], training: bool = False) -> tf.Tensor:
    ...
```

Then when I try to fit my model I get this:

```py
model = MyModel()
...  # Build, compile, callbacks, bla bla
model.fit(
    [X1, X2],
    y,
    validation_data=([X1_val, X2_val], y_val),
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, 
    epochs=NUM_EPOCHS,
    callbacks=[tensorboard_callback, early_stopping_callback, lr_scheduling_callback]
)
```

Produces this error:

```
> ...
>
> ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "my_model" (type MyModel).
> 
> in user code:
>   
> File "/bla/bla/my_model.py", line xx, in call  *
> return self._my_method(inputs, training)
>
> ValueError: Python inputs incompatible with input_signature:
>
> inputs: (
>
>>  (<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None,) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:1' shape=(None, 10) dtype=float32>),
>>
>>  True)
>
> input_signature: (
>
>>   (TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.float32, name='X1'), TensorSpec(shape=(None, 10), dtype=tf.float32, name='X2')),
>>
>>  TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.bool, name='training')).
>   
> Call arguments received:
>
>>   • inputs=('tf.Tensor(shape=(None,), dtype=float32)', 'tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 10), dtype=float32)')
>>
>>  • training=True
```

This feels like a catch-22 situation because on the one hand `input_signature` doesn't allow me to specify a simple `bool`, but on the other hand `model.fit` is passing a `bool` to the training argument and I cannot change this... Any chance to get out of this pickle? Thx!

Comment: Have you simply tried: `y = tf.constant(y, dtype=tf.bool)` in `model.fit`?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: You can't have non-tensor inputs in an input_signature, but you could create a wrapper function with only tensor inputs that sets training=False as in the code below.

The use case is that `self._my_method` can be called during training and then once you've saved and reloaded the trained model, you can call `self.my_method_no_training`.

According to [Tensorflow API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function#input_signatures)

input_signature:

> A possibly nested sequence of tf.TensorSpec objects specifying the
> shapes and dtypes of the Tensors that will be supplied to this
> function. If None, a separate function is instantiated for each
> inferred input signature. **If input_signature is specified, every input
> to func must be a Tensor**, and func cannot accept **kwargs.

Example code:

```py
class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init___(**kwargs):
        ...
        self.batch_norm = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(name="batch_norm")
        ...

    def call(self, inputs: Tuple[tf.Tensor, tf.Tensor], training: bool = False) -> tf.Tensor:
        ...
        some_result = self._my_method(inputs, training)
        ...
        return final_result

    def _my_method(self, inputs: Tuple[tf.Tensor, tf.Tensor], training: bool = False) -> tf.Tensor:
        ...
        x_norm = self.batch_norm(x, training=training)
        ...
        return some_result

    @tf.function(
        input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(shape1), tf.TensorSpec(shape2)]
    )
    def my_method_no_training(self, inputs: Tuple[tf.Tensor, tf.Tensor]) -> tf.Tensor:
        return self._my_method(inputs, training=False)
```

Where shape1 and shape2 are the respective shapes of the two input tensors (e.g. [None, 64, 64, 3])